# Regex to find <input with name>

Tags: c#, regex

I have read this article: [Regex to find input value attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031318/regex-to-find-input-value-attribute)

and modified that regex string to:

```
string regexStr = "(?<1><\s*input\s+[^>]*)(?:(?<2>\sname\s*=\s*)(?<3>\w*find_me\w*)(?<4>[^>\s]*)(?<5>\3))(?<6>[^>]*>)";
var r = new Regex(regexStr, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I'm trying to find this:

```
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="FIND_ME" VALUE="">
```

The above mentioned Regex doesn't find anything.

If i change this: \w*find_me\w* to "" then it finds all inputs.

What is wrong?

1) I need to find INPUT & NAME = "FIND ME"
2) I don't know if any additional params will be there ( they may or may not ), the main is INPUT & NAME = "FIND ME".

Comment: I'm sure you're aware, but using regular expressions to parse HTML is a bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: You will need to find a framework for the language of your choice which allows you to parse HTMl text.

Comment: As npinti points out, HTML is not a regular language and thus not good to parse with regexes.

Comment: As for the regex, you should have at least useda verbatim string literal. As for a solution: use HtmlAgilityPack, and search for an `input` tag that has `name attribute having `FIND_ME` in it. I guess this what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it this way:

```
(?<1><\s*input\s+[^>]*)(?:(?<2>\s*type\s*=\s*)(?<3>[""'])(?<4>[^>\s]*)(?<5>\3))(?:(?<6>\sname\s*=\s*)(?<7>[""'])(?<8>find_me)(?<9>[^>\s]*)(?<10>\3))(?<11>[^>]*>)
```